# Cannot load images in javascript and WebGL because of CORS issues

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm currently trying to load images in javascript so I can load a texture in WebGL but am receiving CORS errors:

```
Access to image at 'http://..../images/earth8k.jpeg' from origin 'http://IPaddress:8800' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my code for initializing the image:

```
function initTextureEarth() {

            earthTexture = gl.createTexture();
            earthTexture.image = new Image();
            earthTexture.image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            earthTexture.image.onload = function () {
                handleLoadedTexture(earthTexture)
            }
            
            earthTexture.image.src = "http://.../images/earth8k.jpeg";
        }
```

I have tried finding a solution online for a couple of hours and I still haven't been able to solve the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have no control over the images (since they are within another origin) then you can fetch them on your serve and then server them to your client.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have control over the images as in I have them locally and on a remote server. I've tried accessing them both ways and I get the same issues.

Comment: If you have images locally, you can try using relative URLs instead of absolute ones.

Comment: Would I still need to be on a live server? Im using the VS code liver server extension